# Ubuntu wants to install on USB rather than hard drive

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, usb

I am trying to dual boot on my laptop. I've set up a partition and created a bootable USB in which I've followed guides to create, but when I try to install Ubuntu by running the installer, but the window says this drive isn't large enough (7.8 GB), referencing my USB stick that is plugged into the laptop.

How do I install directly to the hard drive?

Any help is appreciated! Thanks :)

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu.  I nearly always hit 'try' before I actually do the install. Whilst trying I write down the sizes of my disks & partitions on the back of an envelope (or scrap of paper from my recycle bin) and then use that to make sure it's selected the correct install drive+partition (just like you noticed the 7.8GB was wrong).  The reason for this is that most machines have different bioses, which order drives differently, with many allowing you to re-order drives yourself too.  (I usually use the 'something else' meaning I have to pick partition(s) myself anyway)

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu wasn't recognizing my hard drive. To fix this, I entered the BIOS and switched the SATA mode from RAID into AHCI. After that, my installation worked perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

During the install process, choose the option: `Something Else` when asked which options to use for installing Ubuntu and choose the drive you wish to install it on.

Comment: I do not get the option to select custom when installing. I first get the option to choose a language, then connect to a network, then it tells me my drive is too small.

Comment: while installing ubuntu, you must be getting a third option (either "custom" or "something else".

Comment: @Noah5900 I fixed my answer to what the newest ubuntu uses.

Comment: @Noah5900 could you please take a picture of exactly what happens?

Comment: I found the answer on another thread. I'm not entirely familiar with the terms, but I had to go into the BIOS and switch the mode from RAID into AHCI so that Ubuntu could see my hard drive. After that, the installation worked perfectly!

Comment: @Noah5900, great, please consider marking one answer as correct.