# Asus vivobook s15 Ubuntu 18.04 No installation type

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, grub2, usb, uefi

I'm trying to install Ubuntu on my laptop as dual boot; however, I had some problems.  
 
 Firstly,
I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 from the following website https://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04.5/ by selecting desktop image and I have used etcher downloaded from https://www.balena.io/etcher/ to obtain live usb. In addition, I have disabled turn on fast startup. Also I have shrink 500 gb volume from SSD with total size 1TB. 
 
Then I have used Settings -> Update & Security -> Recovery -> Advanced Startup -> Restart -> Troubleshoot -> Advanced options -> UEFI firmware settings -> Restart to get into BIOS menu. I have done it this way since https://www.asus.com/tr/support/FAQ/1013015/ described it like this. 
 
After these steps, I have disabled secure boot and fast boot options. Finally I have changed ordering of boots and selected USB as the first one. I have looked a lot at whether or not there're other options to be changed, yet I couldn't find something else in BIOS. I have restarted again and selected USB boot. 
 
 There're options like try Ubuntu without installing it and install it. I have selected the first one and tried installing Ubuntu using the icon in the desktop. I have selected language etc. I chose normal installation, but after that, I couldn't find something related with computer. It was probably trying to install Ubuntu on USB. The screen was almost the same with https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDYar.jpg 
 
What can be the possible reasons for it and how can I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Is there another OS already installed on that machine?

Comment: Yes, windows 10 then was already installed

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, the Vivobook S15 windows 10 is probably installed on GPT partition table, UEFI boot only install to the UEFI partition table, in my opinion. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031766/installing-ubuntu-desktop-18-04-lts-but-its-not-detecting-my-samsung-pcie-nvme

Comment: The problem was the same with the following one https://askubuntu.com/a/976509. Thanks.